# How to retrieve the elements' initial property after jQuery task is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with my toggle button rotation. When the menu's property switch from `{display:none}` to `{display:block}` using jQuery. It once rotates 180deg while switching to block but when switched back to none, it remains the same, rotated 180deg. I want it back to initial position when {display:none}.
for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").css({"color":"red"});
    })
});
```

The above button turns the `<p>` elements red; is it possible to retrieve the same initial color back with same button clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, get the color in a variable likethis:

```
var color = $("button").css("color");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        var color = $("button").css("color");
        console.log(color);
        $("button").css({"color":"red"});
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="color:blue">click me</v>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may switch the color value:

```
var pColor = $("p").css("color");
$("p").css({
  "color": (pColor == "red" ? "black" : "red")
});
```

Alternatively, you may use flag:

```
var switchBack = false;
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").css({
    "color": (switchBack ? "red" : "black")
  });
  switchBack = !switchBack;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle class:

```
 $(".red").click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("green");
});
```

see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mo7deve/9t8udLoq/)